# encrypting and serializing stl string and other containers

Tags: c++, serialization, encryption, stl

I have data in stl containers (vector). Each node in the vector is a structure which also contains stl strings.

```
struct record
{
string name;
string location;
int salary;
}

vector< record > employees;
```

I want to serialize employees but I also want to encrypt it before serializing.

my encryption function looks like this:

```
Encode(const char * inBfr, const int in_size, char ** outBfr, int& out_size )
```

By searching it looks like the stl standard doesn't require the memory of my structure to be contiguous so I can't just grab the memory of `employees` variable. Is there any other smart way that I can use this encoding function with my stl based structures/container? It is good for me that Encode function works in plain char * buffers so I know exactly what goes in and out but stl structures are not and I am tring to find a nice way so I can use stl with this function.

I am also opening to using any other stl containers if that helps.

Comment: The memory of `std::vector` must be contiguous (so you can use `&employees[0]`, or with C++11, `employees.data()`). However, the layout of your struct may include padding, depending on the whims of the compiler. Assuming you need to be able to deserialize later, it's probably a bad idea to depend on the layout of the struct.

Comment: That `Encode` function looks like a terrible idea.  The `**` is a sign you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @KevinBallard I said the same thing in an earlier comment and then realized that that'll not work because `std::string` (present in each record) only contains pointers to the data (forget about SSO), so you cannot simply operate on the underlying buffer of the vector.

Comment: @MooingDuck what could be wrong with **? It just means the that function is allocating whatever memory is required and the size is given out in out_size variable. I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: @zadane: It means you probably have memory leaks.  The "correct" C++ thing would probably be a `std::vector<char>&`, or not passing in the outbuffer parameter at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck You are right but I just presented the relevant code, it has to call delete on outBfr but `std::vector<char>&` is still better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the element in the `std::vector<T>` are guaranteed to be laid out contiguously, this doesn't really help: the record you have may include padding and, more importantly, will store the `std::string`'s content external to the `std::string` object (in case the small string optimization is used, the value may be embedded inside the `std::string` but it will also contain a couple of bytes which are not part of the `std::string`s value). Thus, you best option is to format your record and encrypt the formatted string.

The formatting is straight forward but personally I would encapsulate the encoding function into a simple `std::streambuf` so that the encryption can be done by a filtering stream buffer. Given the signature you gave, this could look something like this:

```
class encryptbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* d_sbuf;
    char            d_buffer[1024];
public:
    encryptbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf)
        : d_sbuf(sbuf) {
        this->setp(this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer + sizeof(this->d_buffer) - 1);
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            *this->pptr() = std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->pubsync()? std::char_traits<char>::eof(): std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        char* out(0);
        int   size(0);
        Encode(this->pbase(), this->pptr() - this->pbase(), &out, size);
        this->d_sbuf->sputn(out, size);
        delete[] out; // dunno: it seems the output buffer is allocated but how?
        this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
        return this->d_sbuf->pubsync();
    }
};

int main() {
    encryptbuf    sbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::ostream eout(&sbuf);
    eout << "print something encoded to standard output\n" << std::flush;
}
```

Now, creating an output operator for your records just printing to an `std::ostream` can be used to create an encoded

Comment: For a moment I was shocked to run across a user who knew how the streams worked well enough to simply post an answer like this.  Then I saw the name :D

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful example, I need more time to fully comprehend this :)

Comment: As it is now, should this keep printing the same (encoded) information over and over? **Edit** Ha I found it, and fixed it. (I probably missed some nuance there, but it appears to fix the infinite output and works for longer output tests too)

Comment: Yes, it should call the underlying stream buffer's `pubsync()`. Also, the original version I posted wasn't resetting the buffer (the call to `setp()` was missing). I typed this code on a mobile device without being able to test...

Comment: @DietmarKühl I had come up with the `setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());` independently :) (I'm so proud). As it is this is working fine in my testbed proggy, just so you know. Not much variation in test cases attempted, though. (E.g. no attempt to write >1024 in one go)

Comment: @sehe: I think it useful to know how to create a simple stream buffer and if you found the missing call to `setp()` I'd think you got a good idea how things work. With respect to the buffer, I typically initially test my stream buffers with buffers of funny sizes, e.g., `4`: it is fairly easy to create that much output.

Comment: @DietmarKühl cppreference is not too shabby; Also, I may have read more than I actively remembered in the Josuttis book, once. I just tried with a buffer size of `7` and it worked flawlessly. Kudos for a nice streambuf demo here.

Comment: Boost.Iostreams is also an option if one is interested in adding functionality to a stream.

Comment: This indeed is some advance piece of code! I am wondering what can be done to incorporate Decode function along same lines so data can be read back from file? Thanks!

Comment: @zadane: Well, for decoding you'd override the reading methods. This is actually simpler than `overflow()` because all you really need to do is to provide a new buffer of data when `underflow()` is called an `gptr() == egptr()` (otherwise there are still characters in the buffer; the IOStreams won't call `underflow()` by themselves unless `gptr() == egptr()`). How the decoding looks exactly depends somewhat on what functions need to be called for decoding, of course.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably easiest to serialize your structure into a string, then encrypt the string. For example:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << a_record.name << "\n" << a_record.location << "\n" << a_record.salary;

encode(buffer.str().c_str(), buffer.str().length(), /* ... */);
```

If it were me, I'd probably write `encode` (or at least a wrapper for it) to take input (and probably produce output) in a vector, string, or stream though.

If you want to get ambitious, there are other possibilities. First of all, @MooingDuck raises a good point that it's often worthwhile to overload `operator<<` for the class, instead of working with the individual items all the time. This will typically be a small function similar to what's above:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, record const &r) { 
    return os << r.name << "\n" << r.location << "\n" << r.salary;
}
```

Using this, you'd just have:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << a_record;

encode(os.str().c_str(), os.str().length(), /* ... */);
```

Second, if you want to get really ambitious, you can put the encryption into (for one example) a `codecvt` facet, so you can automatically encrypt all the data as you write it to a stream, and decrypt it as you read it back in. Another possibility is to build the encryption into a filtering `streambuf` object instead. The `codecvt` facet is probably the method that should theoretically be preferred, but the `streambuf` is almost certainly easier to implement, with less unrelated "stuff" involved.

Comment: I'd probably also mention how to overload `<<` for the class, and maybe that one could make a stream that automatically encrypts?

Comment: The problem I see is that after encoding each record this way (separately) what would I write in the file? Possibly `encoded_string_size` followed by `encoded_string` and so on for the whole vector!? The size of each node that I am writing is still not going to be encoded and may require another level of encryption. If I can encode the whole vector in one shot and write the resulting buffer to file that would seem like much easier and simpler to implement. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @zadane: yes: it won't work, since a bitwise copy of a `std::string` doesn't work.  There's a reason Jerry gave this advice and got the upvotes.

Comment: @zadane: you pretty much need to serialize them first, then encrypt. You can encrypt records individually, or you can serialize all of them into one big string, then encrypt that -- but you pretty much need it "flattened" before encrypting.

Comment: Btw if I serialize string via `<<` operator and write it to a file/memory, is it guaranteed to work if I write another program on Macintosh and deserialize the stl string from file using another stl library? Currently I am working in Windows.

Comment: @zadane: nope, there's no such guarantee, due to string encodings, differing type sizes, endianness... sorry man.  Serialization is hard.

Comment: @MooingDuck That was my suspicion and that's why I always serialize strings/data to my own design to be sure I can 100% account for the format of data. Depending on requirements, I would write a byte (or two) followed by number bytes of the string. This way I exactly know what's in the file and I reach it back from anywhere. For other plain data types like float I think << always work consistently on any platform (at least in corresponding 32 or 64 bit environment).

Comment: @zadane: By itself, `string`'s `operator<<` just writes the contents. At the very least, to deserialize, you need (for one example) to do something to separate strings like prefixing with a length, or using a delimiter you know won't occur in the strings. For wide strings, encoding it into a form the other end can understand (e.g., UTF-8) can be necessary as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks, I think that's what I just posted in the above comment to prefix it with length of data.

Comment: @zadane: actually no.  When using `<<` with `short` or `int` (or similar), it is _not_ guaranteed to work consistently, even if the platforms are both 32-bit or whatever, due to endian issues.

Comment: @MooingDuck could that be a limitation, I am curious if there is some way to make it work with little/big endians as well? I guess in that case even prefixing it with length wouldn't make a difference but perhaps prefix it with another byte if its little or big endian!? But that sound like compiler settings, that would be pain!

Comment: @zadane: Yeah -- I saw the "show 1 more comment" as I was typing, but didn't look before I clicked the "add comment" button.

Comment: @zadane: It almost sounds like you want to encode the values as you're streaming them.  I could swear I just saw a question on how to do that...

Comment: @zadane: if you want, you can (for one example) use `htons` (or `htonl`, etc.) to convert to a neutral format first (and obviously use `ntohs`/`ntohl` on the receiving end). Alternatively, consider something like XDR, Google protobufs, Boost serialization, etc.