# How to redirect std::cout to a UITextView?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm adding C++ code to an iOS application, and I would like to use a UITextView as a way to display what's going through std::cout. I don't want to modify the C++ code too much.

So far, I have defined a string stream named stdcout, in the scope of the C++ code I'm interested in capturing the output, and I'm updating the UITextView after the C++ block returns. This is a bit intrusive, as I need to do some manual text replacing, and it's error prone.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: If it's all localized to one file, why not just use the char*'s you're putting to the output stream, and put it in an NSString (with `+stringWithUTF8String:`).  Then call `setText:` as needed

Comment: I don't really want to track every use of std::cout and modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at rdbuf().

If you care about performance/flexibility, you could write a custom stream buffer and implement the overflow members so that you get "automatic" "live" updating.

Here's a simple example relaying to a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    auto saved = std::cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());

    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;

    std::cout.rdbuf(saved);
    return oss.str().length();
}
```

This program exits with exitcode '12' on my cygwin shell:

```
./test.exe; echo $?
12
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with stream buffers. What are overflow members ?

Comment: The best description of the workings of stream buffers IME are in the answers by [Dietmar Kühl](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1120273%20overflow): e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716990/encrypting-and-serializing-stl-string-and-other-containers/12717492#12717492, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943280/c-template-operator-compilation-error/13943353#13943353, (but also [other](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1120273%20buffer) related answers). Be sure to also consider Boost IOStreams.